# How to determine the optimal value to use for Ehcache's maxElements settings?

Tags: ehcache

The currently released versions of Ehcache (2.4.1 is the latest) only support settings to control the maximum number of elements in the cache (maxElementsInMemory, and maxElementsOnDisk). How do you determine what the optimal value is for these two settings?

For example, if I know my maximum heap size is set to 250m, how do I decide what the best value is for maxElementsInMemory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can count that size approximately depending on the size of the entities your are going to put inside the cache but practice shows that that's more like how many entities your application is going to use and depends on the load, complexity and concurrent sessions (or simply concurrent users) your app has. Just simply speaking try playing with numbers, start around 1000 objects and see the memory usage of your app, if it won't go up then it's ok if it's around 500mb the you should target max elements size depending on this value

Comment: This sounds like the right approach, but could you clean your answer up a little bit? Maybe add a bit more detail? An example would go a long way...